Problems with launching jupyter notebook - (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')
After jupyter notebook i got this:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/channels.py", line 12, in <module>
    import zmq.asyncio
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise original_error from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 32, in select_backend
    mod = import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))

Tried to uninstall and install some packages but (zeromq, numpy), but nothing helped.
I have Mac M2

How did you install Python? Jupyter? What did you follow as a guide? I'm concerned because I see Python 3.10 which is dated from three years ago. Probably not what you want? Plus concerned you are trying to use the Python that came on the Mac, which isn't for you. I don't have a concise summary from 2024 but this is probably pertinent to you. (But thread is written for probably advanced users.) I would suggest Anaconda/conda, see here, but you have to learn its management approach.
